Duplicate records getting saved only for a particular table in a Spring Boot microservice using JPA and Hibernate
I have a spring boot microservice which is using JPA and Hibernate to interact with the DB. For only 2 tables sometimes, it is saving duplicate records with a different foreign key. Its code is same as other tables and there I'm not getting this problem. What I have noticed is somehow same multiple requests are getting executed in parallel during the execution of a request but duplicates are only getting saved to 2 tables and not for any other. And one of these tables is outside of any loop but still data is getting persisted multiple times.
I'm not able to recreate this scenario in my local it is happening in DEV env in kubernetes and it is not happening every time.
Any idea if it is an issue with Hibernate>
I have tried recreating this in local as well as DEV env on K8s also but I'm not able to recreate it.

Please add minimum information to reproduce this issue

When dealing with database operations in a Spring Boot application using JPA, it is crucial to correctly handle the distinction between update and create operations to avoid unintentional data duplication. Here are some common issues and best practices to ensure your operations perform as expected.
Update Operation
A common pitfall when performing an update operation is not including the Id field in the entity object. If the Id field is not provided, JPA will assume it is a new entity and generate a new Id, resulting in the creation of a new record instead of updating the existing one.
Example:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructur
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  private String description;

}

When updating an entity, make sure to include the Id:

Create Operation
When creating a new entity, ensure that you are importing the @Id annotation from the correct package. Depending on your Spring Boot version, you should use either javax.persistence.Id or jakarta.persistence.Id. For Spring Boot 3, use the jakarta.persistence.Id annotation.
Debugging with Loggers
To debug and verify when a new Id is being created, add logging statements in your service or repository layer. This will help track the flow of operations and identify if and when a new record is being unintentionally created.
By following these practices, you can ensure that your JPA operations correctly differentiate between create and update operations, avoiding common pitfalls and improving the reliability of your application.
